# Converting human readable time to epoch time

Tags: c

I have to program a function in C using the function prototype

```
time_t convertTimeToEpoch(char* datetime);
```

to convert human readable time to Epoch time.

We are given a `string` timestamp like this "`28/02/2013 17:17:37`".

I have searched on Google and they only help you or tell you how to convert epoch time to human readable time.

I'm pretty new at programming, so I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this function

Comment: Why not use strptime ?

Comment: "Epoch time" is the time since Jan 1, 1970, usually figured in seconds or milliseconds.  See, eg, http://www.epochconverter.com/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Coversion of human readable time to epoc time is a little bit tricky considering the leap year. As per wikipedia epoch time is time spent since 01/01/1970 00:00:00 neglecting leap seconds. I have tried to write a program as per this definition that meets your need. Enjoy :)

INPUT: It should strictly follow the following syntax.

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

for eg, one can enter 2 jan 1971, 5:00:00am as 02/01/1971 05:00:00. Also the year should be in range of 1970

OUTPUT:

```
<time in epoch>
```

Note : i havn't checked it for many test-cases. Notify me if fails anywhere.

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
unsigned int convertTimeToEpoch(char *dateTime);
int days(int,int,int,int,int,int);
int month(int,int);
bool isleapyear(int);
void main(){
char dtArr[19];
char *dateTime;
unsigned int epoc;
dateTime=dtArr;
printf("\nEnter Date time as(DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS)");
scanf(" %[^\n]s",dtArr);
epoc=convertTimeToEpoch(dateTime);
printf("\nepoc time:%d\n",epoc);
}
unsigned int convertTimeToEpoch(char* dateTime){
int char2num(char);
int i,y=0,m=0,d,h,min,sec,day;
unsigned int time;
d= char2num(dateTime[0])*10 + char2num(dateTime[1]);
m= char2num(dateTime[3])*10 + char2num(dateTime[4]);
y= char2num(dateTime[6])*1000 + char2num(dateTime[7])*100 + char2num(dateTime[8])*10 + char2num(dateTime[9]);
h= char2num(dateTime[11])*10 + char2num(dateTime[12]);
min= char2num(dateTime[14])*10 + char2num(dateTime[15]);
sec= char2num(dateTime[17])*10 + char2num(dateTime[18]);
day= days(1970,y,1,m,1,d);
time=((day*24+h)*60+min)*60+sec;
return time;
}
int days(int y1,int y2,int m1,int m2,int d1,int d2){
int count=0,i;
for(i=y1;i<y2;i++){
            if(isleapyear(i))
              count+=366;
           else
              count+=365;
                  }
count-=month(m1,y1);
count-=d1;
count+=month(m2,y2);
count+=d2;
if(count<0)
 count=count*-1;
return count;
 }
int month(int a,int yy){
int x=0,c;
int mon[12]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
for(c=0;c<a-1;c++){
                  if(c==1){
                         if(isleapyear(yy))
                           x+=29;
                         else
                           x+=28;
                          }
                else x+=mon[c];
                }
return(x);
}
bool isleapyear(int year){ 
bool i;
if ( year%400 == 0)
  i=true;
else if ( year%100 == 0)
  i=false;
else if ( year%4 == 0 )
  i=true;
else
  i=false;
return i;
}
int char2num(char c){
int i;
i= (int)c-48;
return i;
}
```

P.S: I havn't written the program to check the input, its all upto the user. If input is feeded in anyother syntax than mentioned, program may lead to a wrong result.